# company-emacs-eclim uses wrong path for project

Tags: eclipse, emacs, eclim, spacemacs

I have a new Emacs setup (on Windows) for a largeish Java/Maven project.

Installed Eclipse and eclim (spacemacs with java layer updated to latest version, company-emacs-eclim installed as extra package), but when company-emacs-eclim tries to autocomplete, it uses the wrong path to the file, inserting the project folder twice, e.g.

```
X:/EclipseWorkspace/Project/Project/src/main/com/company/product/Klass.java
```

instead of

```
X:/EclipseWorkspace/Project/src/main/com/company/product/Klass.java
```

Error message is

```
Company: An error occurred in auto-begin
Company: backend company-emacs-eclim error "Could not read from "file:///X:/EclipseWorkspace/Project/Project/src/main/com/company/product/Klass.java" because it is a not a file." with args (candidates this)
```

In eclimd, I get an exception with the same message:

```
ERROR [org.eclim.command.Main] Command failed
org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not read from "file:///X:/EclipseWorkspace/Project/Project/src/main/com/company/product/Klass.java" because it is a not a file.
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.getInputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1109)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.DefaultFileContent.getInputStream(DefaultFileContent.java:317)
at org.eclim.util.file.FileUtils.byteOffsetToCharOffset(FileUtils.java:75)
at org.eclim.plugin.core.command.AbstractCommand.getOffset(AbstractCommand.java:99)
at org.eclim.plugin.core.command.AbstractCommand.getOffset(AbstractCommand.java:71)
at org.eclim.plugin.core.command.complete.AbstractCodeCompleteCommand.execute(AbstractCodeCompleteCommand.java:60)
at org.eclim.command.Main$1.run(Main.java:100)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4203)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3819)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

I've tried closing and reopening the workspace, reopening the project in Emacs, recreating the entire workspace, everything gives the same result.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I'm seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer seems to be that eclim has incomplete support for multi-module maven projects. See e.g. https://github.com/ervandew/eclim/issues/499.

The problem is not related to `company`, the error is the same calling `eclim-complete`. What seems to happen is that in a multi-module project `eclim--project-current-file` is set to a path relative to the root rather than the current project.

You could work around this by advising `eclim--current-project-file` to return the right relative path. For example:

```
(defun my-eclim-fix-relative-path (path)
  (replace-regexp-in-string "^.*src/" "src/" path))

(advice-add 'eclim--project-current-file :filter-return #'my-eclim-fix-relative-path)
```

This may affect other eclim behavior, but in my quick testing it works for me when I'm working on src/main and src/test files.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the contents of the .classpath file at the root of your project?  That may contain some errors somehow.  If you edit it to point to the right directories, that may fix the autocompletion.

Comment: .classpath is not broken, it points to the correct relative locations